# Query to exclude two or more records if they match a single value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table in which multiple customers can be assigned to multiple types. I am having trouble formulating a query that will exclude all customer records that match a certain type. For example:

```
ID  CustomerName    Type
=========================
111 John Smith      TFS-A 
111 John Smith      PRO 
111 John Smith      RWAY 
222 Jane Doe        PRO 
222 Jane Doe        TFS-A 
333 Richard Smalls  PRO 
444 Bob Rhoads      PRO 
555 Jacob Jones     TFS-B 
555 Jacob Jones     TFS-A
```

What I want is to pull only those people who are marked PRO but not marked TFS. If they are PRO and TFS, exclude them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your data as a *table*.  Also, desired results are also helpful.

Comment: run the code snippet, you will get the results as a table @GordonLinoff

Comment: If you re-write your requirement this way, does it suggest an answer?:  "What I want is to pull only those people where there EXISTS a row of type=PRO and also where there does NOT EXIST a row of type=TFS."

Comment: Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all `'PRO'` customers and use `NOT EXISTS` clause to exclude the ones that are also `'TFS'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, CustomerName
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE [Type] = 'PRO' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                     FROM mytable AS t2
                                     WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND [Type] LIKE 'TFS%')
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/244f1/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select DISTINCT(Customername),ID 
FROM tablename
WHERE NOT (ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tablename WHERE type='PRO')
          AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tablename WHERE type='TFS'))
```

EDIT: now added working TFS clause

Get all customers that do not have TYPE PRO AND TFS for example
SQLFIDDLE:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da4f9/2

Comment: not true, you can set NOT at the front of your clause aswell, check this sqlfiddle, i do have a syntax error, but it is on my distinct, not my where clause

Comment: op still wants all Pro which are not TFS, you select ev1 whos not PRO

Comment: he edited his question after I was already working no the question, I fixed it now, wait no, still need some changes

Comment: and now you select ev1 whos not in both lists but don't care if its a pro without TFS or a TFS without PRO

Comment: I know i still use equal instead of LIKE 'TFS%' but I think he can figure that part out :p

Answer (score 1):

solution using `EXCEPT`

```
WITH TestData
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
    VALUES ( 111, 'John Smith',     'TFS-A' )
    ,      ( 111, 'John Smith',     'PRO'   )
    ,      ( 111, 'John Smith',     'RWAY'  )
    ,      ( 222, 'Jane Doe',       'PRO'   )
    ,      ( 222, 'Jane Doe',       'TFS-A' )
    ,      ( 333, 'Richard Smalls', 'PRO'   )
    ,      ( 444, 'Bob Rhoads',     'PRO'   )
    ,      ( 555, 'Jacob Jones',    'TFS-B' )
    ,      ( 555, 'Jacob Jones',    'TFS-A' )) 
    AS t (ID, CustomerName, [Type])
    )

SELECT ID, CustomerName
FROM TestData
WHERE [Type] = 'PRO'
EXCEPT
SELECT ID, CustomerName
FROM TestData
WHERE [Type] LIKE 'TFS%'
```

output result

[image]

Comment: you filter the RWAY away too. you better write `WHERE [Type] LIKE 'TFS%' ` instead of `WHERE [Type] <> 'PRO'`

Comment: @Aツ this is just an example, but if you insist I will change it)

Comment: i don't insist , its not my question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT *
FROM   table a
WHERE  Type = 'PRO'
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                      FROM   table b
                      WHERE  a.ID = b.ID
                             AND LEFT(Type, 3) = 'TFS')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered, but mine answer is different. Everyone else solutions involves two queries which means what I call "double-dipping". You have to look access the same table twice. It's better to avoid this when possible for better performance. Check this out:

```
SELECT  ID,
        CustomerName,
        MIN([type]) AS [Type] --doesn't matter if it's MIN or MAX
FROM yourTable
WHERE   [Type] = 'PRO' --only load values that matter. Ignore RWAY
        OR [Type] LIKE 'TFS-_' --notice I use a "_" instead of "%". That because "_" is a wildcard for a single character 
                               --instead of wildcard looking for any number of characters because normally it's best to be as narrow as possible to be more efficient
GROUP BY ID,CustomerName
HAVING SUM(CASE 
                WHEN [Type] = 'Pro' --This is where it returns values that only have type PRO
                    THEN 9999       
                ELSE 1
             END
            ) = 9999
```

So let me explain my funky HAVING logic. So as you can see it's a SUM() so and for PRO it's 9999 and TFS-_ it's 1. So when the sum is EXACTLY 9999, then it's good. Why I can't just do a COUNT(*) = 1 is because if a value has only one TFS and no pro, it would be returned, which of course would be incorrect.

**Results:**

```
ID          CustomerName   Type
----------- -------------- -----
444         Bob Rhoads     PRO
333         Richard Smalls PRO
```